# What does it mean to have the processor ignore interrupt request line?

Tags: computer-architecture

I was reading a textbook on COA, it says
[image: I have attached the corresponding passage]

If the processor is going to ignore the interrupt request line till the execution of the first instruction of the ISR, how will it know which device to service?
I mean the processor is ignoring the interrupt requests so how does it acknowledge the request in the first place?

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Comment: We require you to provide proper attribution for the original source of all material originally written by others: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: This mechanism is meant to prevent spurious interrupts *after the initial interrupt has been sensed by the processor*.